# Unable to cast object of type '<OfTypeIterator> to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an interface `IHandler` which could have multiple implementations. I want to call a method in all implementations of `IHandler` and collate the results like the following:

```
var identifiers = new List<Identifier>();
foreach(var handler in _handlers.ToList())
{
    var ids = handler.PreCheck(postData.ClientId).ToList();
    identifiers.AddRange(ids);
}
```

Where `_handlers` is `IEnumerabale<IHandler>` injected in to the constructor.

The `PreCheck` method has the following code in the implementation of `IHandler`:

```
public IList<Identifier> PreCheck(int clientId)
{
    try
    {
        var identifiers = new List<Identifier>();
        var medications = _service.GetAll(clientId, 1, 3, 0);
        foreach(var medication in medications)
        {
            var identifier = new Identifier();
            identifier.ItemIdentifier = medication.MedicationIdentifierId;
            identifier.System = Constants.MODULE_NAME;
            identifiers.Add(identifier);
        }

        return identifiers;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Where the return type of `GetAll` is `List<MedicationModel>`.

On executing the line `var ids = handler.PreCheck(postData.ClientId).ToList();`, this is throwing the exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1[Models.Identifier]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Models.Identifier]'.
```

Update: Code for `IHandler`

```
public interface IHandler : IEventHandler
{
    IList<Identifier> PreCheck(int clientId);
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you add a code for `IHandler`?

Comment: @dotnetom Added code for `IHandler`.

Comment: Is that the only implementation of `IHandler`? `<OfTypeIterator>d__95` would mean `OfType` is called, I do not see why that would be the case... By the way, you should not need `ToList` because `List<Identifier>.AddRange` takes `IEnumerable<Identifier>`, `IList<Identifier>` extends `IEnumerable<Identifier>` and `IHandler.PreChek` returns `IList<Identifier>`. Addendum: you do not need to call `ToList` on `_handlers` either, `foreach` works on `IEnumerabale<IHandler>`.